# Metasploit ruby "bad interpreter: Permission denied"

Tags: kali-linux, ruby

When I'm typing in my terminal `msfconsole` I got something like this:

```
bash: /usr/bin/msfconsole: /usr/share/metasploit-framework/ruby: bad interpreter: Permission denied

ls -l /usr/share/metasploit-framework/ruby
total 276
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root  4096 Aug 24 13:10 2.2.0
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root  4096 Aug 26 03:55 2.3.0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Aug 24 14:19 backward
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  6252 Apr 14 08:16 changelog.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  3036 Apr 14 08:16 copyright
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  4232 Apr 25 19:06 debug.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  5785 Apr 25 19:06 defines.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1316 Jun 18 01:28 digest.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 17849 Apr 25 19:06 encoding.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 36172 Apr 25 19:06 intern.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  5200 Apr 25 19:06 io.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  4953 Apr 25 19:06 missing.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   318 Apr 14 08:16 NEWS.Debian.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 37881 Apr 25 19:06 oniguruma.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1191 Apr 14 08:16 README.Debian
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   777 Apr 25 19:06 regex.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1465 Apr 25 19:06 re.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 69536 Apr 25 19:06 ruby.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  5339 Apr 25 19:06 st.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   374 Apr 25 19:06 subst.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   996 Apr 25 19:06 thread.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1333 Apr 25 19:06 thread_native.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  2050 Apr 25 19:06 util.h
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 Aug 24 14:18 vendor_ruby
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1854 Apr 25 19:06 version.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1677 Apr 25 19:06 vm.h
```

Comment: What version of the `metasploit-framework` package do you have (`dpkg -l metasploit-framework`)? It looks like either a bug in the package or that your system is not up-to-date (mixing an old version of a package and a newer version of another package might do this, though currently it's all in a single package).