# Msfconsole-metasploit framework bad ruby interpreter

Tags: kali-linux

When I type `msfconsole` in my terminal i got something like this:

```
bash: /usr/bin/msfconsole: /usr/share/metasploit-framework/ruby: bad interpreter:
```

Please help me.

After ls -l /usr/share/metasploit-framework/ruby I got:

```
total 276

drwxr-xr-x  9 root root  4096 Aug 24 13:10 2.2.0
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root  4096 Aug 26 03:55 2.3.0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Aug 24 14:19 backward
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  6252 Apr 14 08:16 changelog.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  3036 Apr 14 08:16 copyright
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  4232 Apr 25 19:06 debug.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  5785 Apr 25 19:06 defines.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1316 Jun 18 01:28 digest.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 17849 Apr 25 19:06 encoding.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 36172 Apr 25 19:06 intern.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  5200 Apr 25 19:06 io.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  4953 Apr 25 19:06 missing.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   318 Apr 14 08:16 NEWS.Debian.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 37881 Apr 25 19:06 oniguruma.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1191 Apr 14 08:16 README.Debian
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   777 Apr 25 19:06 regex.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1465 Apr 25 19:06 re.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 69536 Apr 25 19:06 ruby.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  5339 Apr 25 19:06 st.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   374 Apr 25 19:06 subst.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   996 Apr 25 19:06 thread.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1333 Apr 25 19:06 thread_native.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  2050 Apr 25 19:06 util.h
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 Aug 24 14:18 vendor_ruby
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1854 Apr 25 19:06 version.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1677 Apr 25 19:06 vm.h
```

Comment: Review permissions?  There is also this already: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/305843/metasploit-ruby-bad-interpreter-permission-denied#comment537459_305843